# Yii2 sendFile() - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, yii2

Hey guys I am trying to set a download button where a user can download a file, which is uploaded using kartik's File Input Widget(single upload).

The codes resides inside the CRUD generated view/controllers/models.

This is the view button code,

```
        <?= Html::a('Download Uploaded File', ['download', 'id' => $model->form_id], [
    'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
    'data' => [
        'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to download this item?',
        'method' => 'post',
    ],
]) ?>
```

Controller function(Download),

```
public function actionDownload($id) {
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

   $path = Yii::getAlias('@web') . '/uploads';
   $file = '/borang/'.$model->form_id.'.'.$model->file->extension;

   if (file_exists($file)) {

   Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file);

  }
}
```

Controller function(Upload which is inside the create action)

```
public function actionCreate()
    {   

        $model = new FormMovement();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');

            if (!empty($model->file) && $model->validate()) {
                    $model->fm_upload = 'uploads/borang/'.$model->form_id.'.'.$model->file->extension;
                    $model->save();
                    $model->file->saveAs('uploads/borang/'.$model->form_id.'.'.$model->file->extension);
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->form_id]);
            }else{
                $model->save();
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->form_id]);
            }

        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

This is the error log,
'Trying to get property of non-object' in C:\xampp\htdocs\adminsys\frontend\controllers\FormMovementController.php:181

which points to,

```
$file = '/borang/'.$model->form_id.'.'.$model->file->extension;
```

inside the Download action(controller)

Comment: This part `$model->file->extension` was not found in download action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
public function actionDownload($id) {
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    $path = Yii::getAlias('@web') . '/uploads';
    $ext = substr(strrchr($model->file,'.'),1);
    $file = $path.$model->file;
    $download = '/borang/'.$model->form_id.'.'.$ext;
    if(file_exists($file)) 
       Yii::$app->response->sendFile($download);
}
```

[strrchr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php)

Comment: I tried the code and no errors are returned but I got a white page with no content. I put the redirect command to the 'view' page and now its just refreshing the page. Meaning the download link didnt work, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in your download function.You are not saving extension in your model.There are many ways to get extension of file .

```
public function actionDownload($id) {
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

   $path = Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . '/uploads';
   $fileextension=end(explode('.',$model->fm_upload));
   $file = $path.'/borang/'.$model->form_id.'.'.$fileextension;

   if (file_exists($file)) {

   Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file);

  }
}
```

Comment: Like what I did with Insane Skull's method,  tried your codes and same result. no errors are returned but I got a white page with no content. I put the redirect command to the 'view' page and now its just refreshing the page. Meaning the download link didnt work, I guess.

Comment: I have changed the uplaod folder path  to "  $path = Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . '/uploads';" . check my updated answer.

Comment: It works! I cant choose both as the accepted answer but I chose the one that I understood the most. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure set_time_limit, is enabled on the server to get the download option working, as it will be disabled on servers by default.